# "General socket error" when Nginx behind HAProxy using a unix socket

Tags: nginx

I use HAProxy in front of nginx for performance reasons, and I seem to be unable to use a unix socket for communication between HAProxy and Nginx.

HAProxy configuration:

```
backend nginx                                                                                                     
  option forwardfor                                                                                              
  option http-server-close                                                                                        
  server nginx_unix /var/run/nginx-webhook.sock check send-proxy
```

Nginx config:

```
server {                                                                                                         
  listen 8080 proxy_protocol;                                                                                   
  listen unix:/var/run/nginx-webhook.sock proxy_protocol;
  ...
}
```

The socket does exist:

```
$ ls -lah /var/run/nginx-webhook.sock                                                                               
srw-rw-rw- 1 root root 0 Feb  7 19:29 /var/run/nginx-webhook.sock
```

This is the error I get from the HAProxy status page:

[image: HAProxy status page screenshot]

```
Mar 17 14:38:42 app01 haproxy[11597]: Server nginx/nginx_unix is DOWN, reason: Socket error, info: "General socket│
 error (No such file or directory)", check duration: 0ms. 1 active and 0 backup servers left. 0 sessions active, 0│
 requeued, 0 remaining in queue.
```

Not sure what's going wrong; the socket *does* exist after all.

Comment: What Linux distribution is this?

Comment: The distro is Debian 9. Haproxy is version 1.7.5-2 and nginx is 1.10.3.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I had the same problem with **Haproxy 1.8.19** on **Debian Buster** with **Varnish 6.0.3** as backend.

For me, the problem come from **chroot** option in Haproxy configuration :

```
chroot /var/lib/haproxy
```

You have two solutions to fix this :

- Move your's Nginx Unix socket in chroot directory
- Or disable chroot option, but it's not recommended for security reason.

Comment: This unfortunately didn't work for me. I made nginx put the socket in `/var/lib/haproxy` (same as the `chroot` stanza of `haproxy.cfg`) and even after chmod 777, still got a `General socket error (No such file or directory)` error.

Comment: Have you keep your Haproxy config for Nginx backend to `/var/run/nginx-webhook.sock` (this path is relative to chroot) ?

Answer (score 0):

After putting your socket in haproxy chroot, you need to mention socket name without '/' with an address family prefix.

```
server nginx_unix "unix@nginx-webhook.sock" check
```

Make sure that the permissions are correct as well.